# Qt Radio Button only call SLOT() when button is actually checked

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, slot

I've got a group of radio buttons. These are all connected to the same `SLOT(updateImage())`.

Here's how they are set up:

```
connect(m_radio1, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(updateImage());
connect(m_radio2, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(updateImage());
connect(m_radio3, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(updateImage());
```

When changing the radio button from one to the next, this `SLOT()` is called twice, once for de-selecting the previously selected radio button, and once for selecting the clicked radio button.

I was wondering, is there a way to modify my `SLOT()` to only occur in one of these cases, when the clicked item becomes checked?

Thanks

Comment: Cannot understand why the question has been given negatives? It is a valid and useful one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking to connect to the *toggled* signal - you are called whenever the object is toggled. What's surprising?

You could connect to the "clicked" signal which provides a "checked" argument you can test.

Btw; if using a modern Qt version, you should ditch the SIGNAL and SLOTS macros and instead use the new connect() syntax that's checked at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Since your signal have a bool parameter.

```
toggled(bool)
```

you could add that parameter to your SLOT method.Then check if the parameter is checked.

Answer (score 0):

(As a complement: How to do so in Python?) Assume you have a radio button `radio_button` and you would like to connect it to slot `_my_slot` while passing `args` as the arguments, such that `radio_button` only send a signal once it is selected, then you need to add the following:

```
radio_button.clicked.connect(lambda: _my_slot(args))
```